# Is it possible to write metric to Prometheus withous label 'job'?

Tags: database, time-series, prometheus, metrics

I found if I want to ingest data into Prometheus, I have to configure "jobs" in yaml file, therefore a 'job' label is attached to the input data.

However, this feature is not introduced due to the official document. I want to know **whether it is mandatory to have a 'job' label for each of my input data**.

Comment: To be clear, automatic addition of `job` and `instance` labels [is described](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#automatically-generated-labels-and-time-series) in official documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "write metric to Prometheus"? Because usual and recommended way is when Prometheus scrapes metrics. Do you mean something like Remote-Write feature?

Comment: @markalex Hi, thank you!  By 'write metrics' I mean provide samples for Prometheus to scrape. After read the doc, now my question is: if there are always `job` and `instance` labels added to the scraped samples, shouldn't thses labels be considered as part of the data model?

Comment: This label are added by Prometheus itself, and they don't really depend on the way how they are exposed. You can try relabeling config, with droplabel action, but I'm not 100% sure it will work for job label. Data model includes description of labels. Job and instance are added automatically,  but otherwise are the same labels as others, so no, I don't think they need to be mentioned in data model.

Comment: @markalex I mean, that 'added automatically' is the most intrinsical difference from other labels. If these 2 labels are almost necessary or mandatory, I think they could be considered as part of the model on conceptual level like in SQL table always has a name, and on physical level these mandatory label may utilize different index mechanism and makes the performance better ...